# User assigned managed identity with azure function - is it possible?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

I was able set up **System assigned** managed identity for function that listens service bus: I turned on System Assigned identity in my function, changed connection string to '*Endpoint=my_endpoint;Authentication=ManagedIdentity*' and assigned a role for function to use service bus.
My function code snippet is as follows:

```
[FunctionName("MyAwesomeFunction")]
        public static async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("myawesome-queue", Connection = "MyAwesomeConn")] string queueItem)
        {
            // func code
        }
```

Now I'm trying to do the same but using **User assigned** identity: I created managed identity, added it to function and assigned a role for it in service bus. But looks like it doesn't work - messages don't get to my queue. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: what is not working here? can you add more details

Comment: I test it with Service bus explorer and see that my message remains in Active messages and doesn't go further. It means that it does't get to the service bus queue.

Comment: do you have a console log or something to make sure it does not reach the function?

Comment: I just have the following in console log:
<16:27:33> The queue <myawesom-queue> has been successfully retrieved.
And that's it. The Active Message Count remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ManagedIdentity` is not supported by service bus and Queue trigger. You have to use a complete connection string with a shared access signature.

As documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#add-to-your-functions-app